# Switch between splitted file with SPACE + NUMBER instead of CTRL-W (like in spacevim)

Tags: split, spacevim

Right now, when I split a file in VIM, I need to use `CTRL-W + h/j/k/l` to switch between them.

In spacevim (https://spacevim.org/), each file has a number visible in the bar (see picture), and I can just press `SPACE + <number>` in command mode to go to that file. I find that way more convenient than the default `CTRL-W` option. However, I don't want to install spacevim just for this, because it do a lot of other config that I don't like.

[image]

So how could I configure my vimrc to do the same?

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: Note that "window numbers" (unlike "window ids") are assigned depending on current layout (top-left to bottom-right). So even if they are not visible, the window on the left is still "1", and one on the right is "2",

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see window numbers you have to setup statusline (`:h statusline`), for example:

```
set statusline=[%{winnr()}] 
set statusline+=%([\%R%M]\ %)
set statusline+=%<%f
set statusline+=%(\ %y%)
set statusline+=%=
set statusline+=%4(%p%%%)
```

See `winnr()` function in the first line.

To switch to the window with that number you can use built-in `2` `C-ww`

You can add mappings:

```
nnoremap <space>1 1<C-w>w
nnoremap <space>2 2<C-w>w
nnoremap <space>3 3<C-w>w
nnoremap <space>4 4<C-w>w
nnoremap <space>5 5<C-w>w
nnoremap <space>6 6<C-w>w
"...
```

Probably it could be done the other way.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I can successfully switch with `SPACE` but I don't see the number in the status line. Could it be because I use the `airline` plugin?

Comment: Yes, you have to setup airline to show window numbers (my example is for a standard statusline)